# Metrics (Distances) on $\mathbb{F}$ Theorem Proof

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, ordered-fields

I had a question regarding a Theorem I had come across that described metrics (distances) on ordered field $\mathbb{F}.$ Here it is:

**Theorem:** If $\mathbb{F}$ is an ordered field, then $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{F}.$

I was told to use this other theorem to support the proof:

**Theorem:** Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an ordered field and $x,y\in\mathbb{F}.$ Then

(a) $|x|\geq0$ and $|x|=0\Leftrightarrow{x}=0;$

(b) $|x|=|-x|;$

(c) $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|.$

I would like to know how I could approach this or you could possibly show me how you would prove it.

Comment: A metric usually takes values in $[0, \infty)$. Here $d$ takes values in $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Nothing. I was just pointing out a fact that you may or may not have been aware of.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ok. Thanks. But I need information pertaining to proving this theorem.

Comment: You seem to be missing a key point. If $\mathbb{F}$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, what is defined in the question is not a metric because $d$ does not take values in $[0, \infty)$. Maybe the theorem you came across was using a more general definition of metric. If that's the case, then you should mention that in your post. Without this clarification, there isn't much more to say.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ok. I will fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a field and $x,y \in \mathbb{F}$, then $x-y\in \mathbb{F}.$

Here is the first condition: Using (a), we have $|x−y|≥0$ and $|x-y|=0⇔x-y=0$,  hence $d(x,y)≥0$ and $d(x,y)=0⇔x=y$

Here is the second condition: Using (b), we have $|x−y|=|−(x-y)|=|y−x|$, hence $d(x,y)=d(y,x).$

And the third condition:  Using (e), we have $|x−y|=|(x−z)+(z-y)|≤|x-z|+|z-y|$, hence $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) + d(z,y).$

Comment: So how do you think I should approach this? How do I prove $|x-y|$ as a metric on $\mathbb{F}.$

Comment: This is the first condition, can you do the second?

Comment: OK. So here is the second and the third condition: Using (b), we have $|x-y|=|-x+y|$, hence $d(x,y)=d(y,x).$ Using (e), we have $|x-y|\leq|x|-|y|$, hence $d(x,y)\leq{d}(x)-d(y)$ Let me know if either is correct.

Comment: You are not correct!

Comment: Then please tell me what I did wrong!

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Here, I combined here answers and flag the rest of the answers to be taken down.